# Can not access protected method in the sub class

Tags: java, clone

Why I can not use clone() method in `public class Object`? `clone()` method is `protected` int the Object class and all classed are sub classes of Object class. `protected` methods can be accessed from sub classes and from classed in the same package. So why I have such an error?

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test2 c1 = new Test2();
        Test2 c2 = (Test2) c1.clone(); // error: clone() has protected access in java.lang.Object
    }
}

class Test2 implements Cloneable
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clone()` is in `java.lang.Object`, and your `Test` class is not in the `java.lang` package. In other words, `protected` doesn't quite mean what you think it means.

The fix is trivial. add this to your Test2:

```
class Test2 implements Cloneable {
    @Override public Test2 clone() {
        return (Test2) super.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: but all classes inherited from ```Object``` class, and protected methods can be access from sub classes in the different package.

Comment: @Denis_newbie according to the _javadoc_ for method `clone()` in class `java.lang.Object`, classes that override method `clone()` must also implement interface `Cloneable`. There is a section devoted to the topic of cloning in the book _Effective Java_ by Josh Bloch.

Comment: @Denis_newbie You've misunderstood that part of the spec. The access modifier 'protected' does not work that way.